# Manifest.json extensión Chrome

Tags: extensión-google-chrome

Estoy desarrollando una extensión de autocompletar formularios en Chrome, para poder manipular los valores de los inputs de los formularios tengo pensado hacerlo a través de un archivo javascript con múltiples algoritmos, pero para poder manipular los inputs de las otras páginas a través del javascript de la extensión obviamente deben estar enlazados, para hacer eso se hacen las declaraciones en el manifest.json:

Ejemplo

-página web olx

"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["http://www.olx.com/"],
"js": ["myscript.js"],
"run_at": "document_end"
}

Pero uno como desarrollar desconoce a que páginas ingresaría el usuario para hacer uso de la extensión como puede estar en olx y después en mercado libre o eBay o otras.

Mi pregunta es hay alguna forma de cambiar el "matches" del manifest.json de manera dinámica(programable)

Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar cambiando el

```
"matches": ["http://www.olx.com/"],
```

Por

```
"matches": ["http://www.olx.com/*"],
```

Ya que de está manera estás diciendo "cualquier página" dentro de olx.com